# Can't find module in local dir, present in sys.path

Tags: python

I'm confused.  I think this is going to be a simple error, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.  I'm running python 2.4.4.  I've written my first python script consisting of multiple files.  I've read python looks in the current working directory, as well as all the usual paths for user-added modules.  I've confirmed this by looking at sys.path:

```
$ python
Python 2.4.4 (#1, Jan  8 2013, 09:29:21) 
[GCC 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2)] on linux3
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/local/lib/python24.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.4',     '/usr/local/lib/python2.4/plat-linux3', '/usr/local/lib/python2.4/lib-tk',     '/usr/local/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages']
>>>
```

The first entry, '', represents look in the current working directory, yet it does not seem to be doing so.  Here is the contents of my mult file python program.  Note, everything is in the same directory:

```
$ ls
cherwellTicket.py  dsutils.py  emailMessage.py
$
```

Here is the contents of dsutils.py.  This module contains various static methods I want to use in other classes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import getpass
import socket

class DSUtils:
    # (I didn't paste the rest)
```

And here is the contents of cherwellTicket.py.  Note, this is in the same directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import DSUtils 

class CherwellTicket:

    def __init():
        pass
```

Yet,  when python trys to execute cherwellTicket.py,  heres what happens:

```
$ python cherwellTicket.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cherwellTicket.py", line 3, in ?
    import DSUtils 
ImportError: No module named DSUtils
$
```

Both files are in the same directory,  so why is the `cherwellTicket` script now able to import the dsutils class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DSUtils` is different than `dsutils`.  I think you might want:

```
from dsutils import DSUtils
```

The *module* is the name of the *file* (sans `.py` extension).  Python doesn't look at the classes within a module until the module is being imported.

Alternatively,

```
 import dsutils
 class_you_want = dsutils.DSUtils
```

Comment: Oh.  Thanks!  Is it considered bad form to name the class differently than the filename?  Is this one of those you can doit but its rude things?

Comment: use CamelCase for classes (pep-8) instead of `class_you_want`. Also the OP is on Linux but on Windows and OS X there is still PYTHONCASEOK envvar (that shouldn't be used), see [Import on Case-Insensitive Platforms](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0235/).

Comment: @mystupidquestion: use lowercase for modules and [CapWords for classes](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names). You can define more than one public class in a module. There is no need to use the same name.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- You're absolutely correct about CapWords for classes.  I only bound a reference to the class under a different name to deminstrate that the class OP wanted would be referenced as `dsutils.DSUtils` when imported that way.

Answer (score 0):

The module is named after the filename, not the class in the module try:

```
from dsutils import DSUtils
```